# Help with Marketing Cloud query and percentages

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I have setup a bunch of DEs that track sends, opens, clicks, etc.

I am trying to aggregate these into a summary DE using the query below. The query runs fine and populates the target DE, but I cannot get the percentages to work. They simply show as 0.00

The fields in the DE are set as type Decimal (3,2).

I have tried all manner of combinations of CAST as Decimal, CAST as FLOAT, etc. But cannot get it to work. I also tried just hard coding some numbers into the query that give a whole number answer, and this works - so I know it's an issue with the decimal places.

Any help on getting this to work would be much appreciated!

```
    SELECT 
    res.CampaignName,
    res.Channel,
    res.Total_Sent,
    res.Total_Opened,
    CAST((res.Total_Opened / res.Total_Sent) * 100) AS DECIMAL(3,2)) AS Percent_Opened,
    res.Total_Clicked,
    (res.Total_Clicked / res.Total_Sent) * 100 AS Percent_Clicked,
    res.Total_Bounced,
    (res.Total_Bounced / res.Total_Sent) * 100 AS Percent_Bounced,
    res.Total_Unsubscribed,
    (res.Total_Unsubscribed / res.Total_Sent) * 100 AS Percent_Unsubscribed
FROM
    (SELECT 
        CT.CampaignName,
            CT.Channel,
            COUNT(S.SubscriberKey) AS Total_Sent,
            COUNT(O.SubscriberKey) AS Total_Opened,
            COUNT(C.SubscriberKey) AS Total_Clicked,
            COUNT(B.SubscriberKey) AS Total_Bounced,
            COUNT(U.SubscriberKey) AS Total_Unsubscribed
    FROM
        CampaignTracking AS CT
    INNER JOIN Tracking_Sent AS S ON CT.SubscriberKey = S.SubscriberKey
        AND CT.JobID = S.JobID
        AND CT.BatchID = S.BatchID
    LEFT JOIN Tracking_Open AS O ON S.SubscriberKey = O.SubscriberKey
        AND S.JobID = O.JobID
        AND S.BatchID = O.BatchID
        AND S.ListID = O.ListID
    LEFT JOIN Tracking_Click AS C ON S.SubscriberKey = C.SubscriberKey
        AND S.JobID = C.JobID
        AND S.BatchID = C.BatchID
        AND S.ListID = C.ListID
    LEFT JOIN Tracking_Bounce AS B ON S.SubscriberKey = B.SubscriberKey
        AND S.JobID = B.JobID
        AND S.BatchID = B.BatchID
        AND S.ListID = B.ListID
    LEFT JOIN Tracking_Unsubscribe AS U ON S.SubscriberKey = U.SubscriberKey
        AND S.JobID = U.JobID
        AND S.BatchID = U.BatchID
        AND S.ListID = U.ListID
    WHERE
        CT.Channel = 'Email'
    GROUP BY CT.CampaignName , CT.Channel) res
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried outputting the results to a text field and see what the result looks like?

One thing I can think that could cause behaviour is that your decimal fields are 3,2 length - so max length is 3 and 2 after the decimal so expect the maximum value you might be able to return is 9.99

William

Answer (score 1):

Thanks William, you were spot on with the 3,2 length issue! I thought 3,2 meant 000.00, but as you point out, 3,2 is actually 0.00.

I changed to 5,2 for the field length. I also changed the query to have the following format for the percentage lines:

```
CAST((CAST(res.Total_Opened AS FLOAT)/CAST(res.Total_Sent AS FLOAT))*100 AS FLOAT) AS Percent_Opened
```